# pyspark: Explode struct into columns

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have created an udf that returns a StructType which is not nested. Simply a and array of mixed types (int, float) with field names. I want to explode /split them into separate columns. Note that this will create roughly 50 new columns. Through googling I found this solution:

```
df_split = df.select('ID', 'my_struct.*')
```

This works. However performance is absolutely terrible, eg. unusable. Checking on the cluster nodes this also uses only 1 core. But this only explains a small part of the issue.

So what would be a good way to achieve my goal and why is above solution so slow?

EDIT:

it seems to be the specific combination of the udf and the splitting that results in the poor performance. This is slow:

```
df_udf = df.withColumn('udf', my_udf(df.input))
df_exploded = df_udf.select('input', 'udf.*')
df_exploded.show(5)
```

This is fast:

```
df_udf = df.withColumn('udf', my_udf(df.input))
df_udf.cache()
df_exploded = df_udf.select('input', 'udf.*')
df_exploded.show(5)
```

Comment: Is your problem solved by what you put in the "EDIT"?  If so, you can make that an answer and accept it so that people don't spend time trying to solve something that's already done.

Comment: Well it does slove toe issue for me specifically, but I'm not sure it's a general viable solution. This is a project for education and running on a tiny cluster only I use and have full control over. AFAIK cache on a large dataset can put the cluster on some serious memory stress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request I'm making my edit the answer. Please take into account, that this worked in my case on a tiny test cluster (5 nodes) with only me working on it with relatively small data set (50 million).

It seems to be the specific combination of the udf and the splitting that results in the poor performance. This is slow:

```
df_udf = df.withColumn('udf', my_udf(df.input))
df_exploded = df_udf.select('input', 'udf.*')
df_exploded.show(5)
```

This is fast:

```
df_udf = df.withColumn('udf', my_udf(df.input))
df_udf.cache()
df_exploded = df_udf.select('input', 'udf.*')
df_exploded.show(5)
```